# redis get returns null even though value exists

Tags: redis, node-redis

I'm struggling to find out what's the problem with redis.

I'm adding a record using the `npm redis` library, which I can see in Medis, which I use to explore Redis.

When I use `GET *key*` i don't get the value back but instead I get `null`. If I rename the key to something else I do get the value back. Also, if I rename the key to its name, I get the value back, too. What could be the problem?

Here are two screenshot to show the problem.

[image]

after rename to the same key

[image]

Comment: Did you check you don't have any extra special char in the first key?

Comment: No I don't have a special character.

Comment: Can you call EXISTS on the key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just used a different key for `voted`. I assume `voted` is reserved for some reason.